# Matching the occurrence and pattern of characters of String2 in String1

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I was asked this question in a phone interview for summer internship, and tried to come up with a n*m complexity solution (although it wasn't accurate too) in Java.

I have a function that takes 2 strings, suppose "common" and "cmn". It should return True based on the fact that 'c', 'm', 'n' are occurring in the same order in "common". But if the arguments were "common" and "omn", it would return False because even though they are occurring in the same order, but 'm' is also appearing after 'o' (which fails the pattern match condition)

I have worked over it using Hashmaps, and Ascii arrays, but didn't get a convincing solution yet! From what I have read till now, can it be related to Boyer-Moore, or Levenshtein Distance algorithms?

Hoping for respite at stackoverflow! :)

**Edit**: Some of the answers talk about reducing the word length, or creating a hashset. But per my understanding, this question cannot be done with hashsets because occurrence/repetition of each character in first string has its own significance. PASS conditions- "con", "cmn", "cm", "cn", "mn", "on", "co". FAIL conditions that **may seem otherwise**- "com", "omn", "mon", "om". These are FALSE/FAIL because "o" is occurring before as well as after "m". Another example- "google", "ole" would PASS, but "google", "gol" would fail because "o" is also appearing before "g"!

Comment: If I understand correctly - `como` will match but `cmo` will not, can you explain what the rule for a match is?

Comment: "...but 'm' is also appearing after 'o' (which fails the pattern match condition)..." - what is that supposed to mean? In your pattern - `omn` - `m` is also appearing after `o`. Why then does it "fail the match condition"? You need to provide a more precise description of the match condition. What you have now doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: these questions did come across my mind later, but in the nervousness of interview, and haste to finish it, I couldn't ask :(
@AndreyT- anyhow, what I understood is- if the string to compare is "omn", then 'o,m,n' are appearing in the same order, but if your algorithm checked for 'o' to be appearing before 'm', then 'o' is also appearing after 'm', which probably is a fail condition for their order of appearance. I hope I made it a little more clear?

Comment: @MadTest Was this google interview question by chance?

Comment: Just confirming, do 'mo' yield False?

Comment: What about if the *second* string contains repeated characters?  TBH, I suspect the interviewer intended to ask you to write a plain longest-common-substring algorithm, but either s/he bungled the explanation of what's required or you misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's quite simple. Run through the pattern and fore every character get the index of it's last occurence in the string. The index must always increase, otherwise return false.
So in pseudocode:

```
index = -1
foreach c in pattern
    checkindex = string.lastIndexOf(c)
    if checkindex == -1                   //not found
        return false
    if checkindex < index
        return false
    if string.firstIndexOf(c) < index     //characters in the wrong order
        return false
    index = checkindex
return true
```

**Edit:** you could further improve the code by passing `index` as the starting index to the `lastIndexOf` method. Then you would't have to compare `checkindex` with `index` and the algorithm would be faster.

**Updated:** Fixed a bug in the algorithm. Additional condition added to consider the order of the letters in the pattern.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more with relevant example? What do you mean by Pattern? Also, its been discussed in the other answers that this is not possible by merely storing the lastIndex of any character and then comparing with it!

Comment: In your intial example, `pattern` is the string "cmn", `string` is "common". But you're right, my algorithm would incorrectly return true for the pattern "mon". But this can easily be fixed by adding an additional check, whether the current pattern character also appears at a lower index. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to implement in my answer with the use of Hash tables. The in built functions which you have used, gives you a running time of a minimum O(n^2). With the help of Hash tables it can be limited to O(n).

Comment: You're right: the running time heavily depends on the implementations of the indexOf functions. If they use pre-calculated Hashtables your and my solution are very similar. (as I see now) A classical time-memory-tradeoff.

Comment: @Raymi, @NirmalGeo- I can understand that your solutions converge at a common point. In fact, I have even implemented it using Raymi's solution. Further it depends where would we tradeoff in terms of time and space complexity. But I was curious why is the time complexity of indexOf() and lastIndexOf() O(n^2)?

Comment: The complexity of the indexOf and lastIndexOf methods should be O(n). O(n^2) is the time complexity of the whole algorithm (well, O(m*n) actually, if this is distinguished in the Big-Oh notation).

Comment: @raymi: how about string="comnonmomn" and pattern="omn"

Comment: Should fail because "m" is also appearing before "o".

Answer (score 2):

An excellent question and couple of hours of research and I think I have found the solution. First of all let me try explaining the question in a different approach.

**Requirement:**

Lets consider the same example 'common' (mainString)  and 'cmn'(subString). First we need to be clear that any characters can repeat within the mainString and also the subString and since its pattern that we are concentrating on, the index of the character play a great role to. So we need to know:

- Index of the character (least and highest)

Lets keep this on hold and go ahead and check the patterns a bit more. For the word common, we need to find whether the particular pattern cmn is present or not. The different patters possible with common are :- (Precedence apply )

- c -> o
- c -> m
- c -> n
- o -> m
- o -> o
- o -> n
- m -> m
- m -> o
- m -> n
- o -> n

At any moment of time this precedence and comparison must be valid. Since the precedence plays a huge role, we need to have the index of each unique character Instead of storing the different patterns.

**Solution**

First part of the solution is to create a Hash Table with the following criteria :-

1. Create a Hash Table with the key as each character of the mainString
2. Each entry for a unique key in the Hash Table will store two indices i.e lowerIndex and higherIndex
3. Loop through the mainString and for every new character, update a new entry of lowerIndex into the Hash with the current index of the character in mainString.
4. If Collision occurs, update the current index with higherIndex entry, do this until the end of String

Second and main part of pattern matching :-

1. Set Flag as False
2. Loop through the subString and for
   every character as the key, retreive
   the details from the Hash.
3. Do the same for the very next character.
4. Just before loop increment, verify two conditions

   ```
   If highestIndex(current character) > highestIndex(next character) Then
      Pattern Fails, Flag <- False, Terminate Loop
      // This condition is applicable for almost all the cases for pattern matching

   Else If lowestIndex(current character) > lowestIndex(next character) Then
      Pattern Fails, Flag <- False, Terminate Loop
      // This case is explicitly for cases in which patterns like 'mon' appear
   ```
5. Display the Flag

N.B : Since I am not so versatile in Java, I did not submit the code. But some one can try implementing my idea

Comment: @Nirmal-Thanks for your solution! the only concern I find with Hashtable is they take time in creation and are not so predictable, although the access time is surely O(1)! and here we would have to create either two Hashtables for storing min and max Indexes, or encounter collisions to update them :)

Answer (score 1):

I had myself done this question in an inefficient manner, but it does give accurate result! I would appreciate if anyone can make out an an efficient code/algorithm from this!

Create a function "Check" which takes 2 strings as arguments. Check each character of string 2 in string 1. The order of appearance of each character of s2 should be verified as true in S1.

1. Take character 0 from string p and traverse through the string s to find its index of first occurrence.
2. Traverse through the filled ascii array to find any value more than the index of first occurrence.
3. Traverse further to find the last occurrence, and update the ascii array
4. Take character 1 from string p and traverse through the string s to find the index of first occurence in string s
5. Traverse through the filled ascii array to find any value more than the index of first occurrence. if found, return False.
6. Traverse further to find the last occurrence, and update the ascii array

As can be observed, this is a bruteforce method...I guess O(N^3)

```
public class Interview
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (check("google", "oge"))
        System.out.println("yes");
    else System.out.println("sorry!");
}

 public static boolean check (String s, String p) 
{   

     int[] asciiArr =  new int[256];    
     for(int pIndex=0; pIndex<p.length(); pIndex++) //Loop1 inside p
     {
        for(int sIndex=0; sIndex<s.length(); sIndex++) //Loop2 inside s
        {
            if(p.charAt(pIndex) == s.charAt(sIndex))    
            {
                asciiArr[s.charAt(sIndex)] = sIndex; //adding char from s to its Ascii value

                for(int ascIndex=0; ascIndex<256; )     //Loop 3 for Ascii Array
                {
                    if(asciiArr[ascIndex]>sIndex)           //condition to check repetition
                    return false;
                    else ascIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
     }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: If Complexity was not an issue, then this is a straightforward one.

Comment: I agree, but I posted this question to know if there is any specific algorithm or method to do such type of question?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it doable in O(n log n)?

Step 1, reduce the string by eliminating all characters that appear to the right.  Strictly speaking you only need to eliminate characters if they appear in the string you're checking.

```
/** Reduces the maximal subsequence of characters in container that contains no
 * character from container that appears to the left of the same character in
 * container.  E.g. "common" -> "cmon", and "whirlygig" -> "whrlyig".
 */
static String reduceContainer(String container) {
  SparseVector charsToRight = new SparseVector();  // Like a Bitfield but sparse.
  StringBuilder reduced = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = container.length(); --i >= 0;) {
    char ch = container.charAt(i);
    if (charsToRight.add(ch)) {
      reduced.append(ch);
    }
  }
  return reduced.reverse().toString();
}
```

Step 2, check containment.

```
static boolean containsInOrder(String container, String containee) {
  int containerIdx = 0, containeeIdx = 0;
  int containerLen = container.length(), containeeLen == containee.length();
  while (containerIdx < containerLen && containeeIdx < containeeLen) {
    // Could loop over codepoints instead of code-units, but you get the point...
    if (container.charAt(containerIdx) == containee.charAt(containeeIdx)) {
      ++containeeIdx;
    }
    ++containerIdx;
  }
  return containeeIdx == containeeLen;
}
```

And to answer your second question, no, Levenshtein distance won't help you since it has the property that if you swap the arguments the output is the same, but the algo you want does not.

Comment: This will return true for the 2nd example where it should return false - `containsInOrder("common", "omn")=true`

Comment: Will edit to show how you can add a pass that removes all letters from the container that occur later in the string.

Comment: @Mike- Thanks for responding, but I tried a similar logic earlier and found it to be failing. Suppose the strings are- "common", "cmo"...according to your logic it would Pass because "cmon" is the reduced string. But it should fail because 'o' is also occurring before 'm' in the original string.

Comment: What I understand is that every character's indexes in both strings must be tracked and verified. It would Pass when- 1. Each character of second string appears in the same fashion as in the original string! But the complexity increases when characters are repeated in first string. How should that be handled?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputContainer = "common";
        String inputContainees[] = { "cmn", "omn" };
        for (String containee : inputContainees)
            System.out.println(inputContainer + " " + containee + " "
                    + containsCommonCharsInOrder(inputContainer, containee));

    }

    static boolean containsCommonCharsInOrder(String container, String containee) {
        Set<Character> containerSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>() {
            // To rearrange the order
            @Override
            public boolean add(Character arg0) {
                if (this.contains(arg0))
                    this.remove(arg0);
                return super.add(arg0);
            }
        };
        addAllPrimitiveCharsToSet(containerSet, container.toCharArray());
        Set<Character> containeeSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
        addAllPrimitiveCharsToSet(containeeSet, containee.toCharArray());

        // retains the common chars in order
        containerSet.retainAll(containeeSet);
        return containerSet.toString().equals(containeeSet.toString());

    }

    static void addAllPrimitiveCharsToSet(Set<Character> set, char[] arr) {
        for (char ch : arr)
            set.add(ch);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
common cmn true
common omn false
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but it returns TRUE for "mon", which is actually a false condition! :(

Comment: @MadTest: why should it be false ? Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this as one of the worst pieces of code I have ever written or one of the worst code examples in stackoverflow...but guess what...all your conditions are met! 
No algorithm could really fit the need, so I just used bruteforce...test it out...
And I could just care less for space and time complexity...my aim was first to try and solve it...and maybe improve it later!

```
public class SubString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubString ss = new SubString();
        String[] trueconditions = {"con", "cmn", "cm", "cn", "mn", "on", "co" };
        String[] falseconditions = {"com", "omn", "mon", "om"};

        System.out.println("True Conditions : ");
        for (String str : trueconditions) {
            System.out.println("SubString? : " + str + " : " + ss.test("common", str));
        }
        System.out.println("False Conditions : ");
        for (String str : falseconditions) {
            System.out.println("SubString? : " + str + " : " + ss.test("common", str));
        }
        System.out.println("SubString? : ole : " + ss.test("google", "ole"));
        System.out.println("SubString? : gol : " + ss.test("google", "gol"));
    }

    public boolean test(String original, String match) {
        char[] original_array = original.toCharArray();
        char[] match_array = match.toCharArray();

        int[] value = new int[match_array.length];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < match_array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = index; j < original_array.length; j++) {
                if (original_array[j] != original_array[j == 0 ? j : j-1] && contains(match.substring(0, i), original_array[j])) {

                    value[i] = 2;
                } else {
                    if (match_array[i] == original_array[j]) {
                        if (value[i] == 0) {
                            if (contains(original.substring(0, j == 0 ? j : j-1), match_array[i])) {
                                value[i] = 2;
                            } else {
                                value[i] = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        index = j + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int b : value) {
            if (b != 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean contains(String subStr, char ch) {
        for (char c : subStr.toCharArray()) {
            if (ch == c) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

-IvarD

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is not a test of your computer science fundamentals, more what you would practically do within the Java programming environment.

You *could* construct a **regular expression** out of the second argument, i.e ...

```
omn -> o.*m[^o]*n
```

... and then test candidate string against this by either using [String.matches(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) or using the [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

In generic form, the construction of the RegExp should be along the following lines.

> exp -> **in[0]**.* + for each x : 2 -> in.lenght { (**in[x-1]** +
>   **[^in[x-2]]*** + **in[x]**) }

for example:

> demmn -> d.*e[^d]*m[^e]*m[^m]*n

Comment: You can't do it with a regular expression as simple as yours, because "mon" should fail (whereas the derived `.*m.*o.*n.*` wouldn't). But probably it's solvable with a more complex regex, where you replace the `.` with 'the preceeding or the following pattern character or any character not in the pattern)'. So something like `[^on]*m[^n]*o[^m]*n[^mo]*` (I'm not a regexpert).

Comment: actually, you are right, I will update the answer with a better RegExp

Comment: I think you have to include every character in the NOT-Expression ([^]), that is not in the right order (i.e. is not the character to the left or right of the NOT-expression). Meaning your `[^e]` in the middle of your example would become something like [^den]. Then you also have to add an expression to the beginning and the end of the pattern. This will give you something like this (for your example): `[^emn]*d[^mn]*e[^dn]*m[^den]*m[^de]*n[^dem]*`

Comment: This is true, but I suppose that what I am really trying to suggest is to delegate the problem to already existing facilities of the class library *before* trying to use your own technique.

Comment: It's certainly a good idea to delegate the problem to existing pieces of software if possible. But talking about regular expressions never forget what Jamie Zawinski said: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself in a different way. Just sharing my solution.

public class PatternMatch {

```
public static boolean matchPattern(String str, String pat) {

    int slen = str.length();
    int plen = pat.length();
    int prevInd = -1, curInd;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < slen; i++) {

        curInd = pat.indexOf(str.charAt(i));


        if (curInd != -1) {

            if(prevInd == curInd)
                continue;
            else if(curInd == (prevInd+1))
                count++;
            else if(curInd == 0)
                count = 1;
            else count = 0;

            prevInd = curInd;
        }


        if(count == plen)
            return true;

    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean r = matchPattern("common", "on");
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

}